# How to ignore one of observables in combineLatest, but have its latest available in the combiner function?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, combinelatest

I have this real world scenario.

I have a ReaderConfig object, which is a dumb tuple of ReaderTheme, ReaderFont, ReaderFontSize. Its changes will trigger the readerConfigObservable which then redraws stuff.

So the solution sofar is

```
combineLatest(themeObservable, fontObservable, fontSizeObservable, 
    (theme, font, fontSize) -> new ReaderConfig(theme, font, fontSize))
```

However, because this is android, ReaderTheme sets some android R.theme. stuff, which need to restart Activity for them to take effect. So I need to expose the themeObservable by it self also

```
themeObservable.subscribe(__ -> activity.recreate())
```

Since it restarts the activity, theres no need for it to trigger the combineLatest, which triggers redraw and allocates resources, only to be disposed of 1 second later because of the restart.

So only fontObservable and fontSizeObservable changes should trigger the combineLatest, HOWEVER I do need the latest themeObservable value in order to construct the ReaderConfig object.

My workaround is this

```
public Observable<ReaderConfig> readerConfigObservable() {
        return Observable.combineLatest(
                mFontRelay, mFontSizeRelay, (__, ___) -> createReaderConfig());
    }

    public ReaderConfig createReaderConfig() {
        return new ReaderConfig(mThemeRelay.getValue(), mFontRelay.getValue(), mFontSizeRelay.getValue());
    }
```

**So basically it *pulls* the themeObservable in the combiner function which is not really reactive,** is there any proper solution for this exception use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this could be solved using `withLatestFrom(...)`:

> Merges the specified ObservableSource into this ObservableSource sequence by using the resultSelector function only when the source ObservableSource (this instance) emits an item.

See the marbles diagram: http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom

Example:

```
.combineLatest(fontObservable, fontSizeObservable, 
    (font, size) -> new FontConfig(font, size))
.withLatestFrom(themeObservable,
    (fontConfig, theme) -> new ReaderConfig(theme, fontConfig.font, fontConfig.size))
```

Comment: Doesnt withLatestFrom emit when themeObservable emits?

Comment: @urSus no, it only emits when the source observable emits.

Comment: oh thats exactly what I need! I thought it was just a shorthand for combinelatest, i.e. symetry for zipWith, mergeWith, etc.

Comment: @urSus I added the link to the marbles diagram so its easier to see :)

Comment: yea, when I google "rxjava withLatestFrom" combineLatest comes up hence my assumption, thanks!